# Formless admin/config page

Tags: 7

I'm a n00b regarding Drupal (I'm using Drupal 7), and I learned how to do a simple form for a configuration page. Currently I have this code:

In toyotaec.info (this one will appear in the module 'configuration' link):

```
configure = admin/config/toyotaec
```

In toyotaec.module:

```
function toyotaec_menu() {
    return array(
        //...
        'admin/config/toyotaec' => array(
            'title' => 'Configuración de Toyota del Ecuador',
            'description' => 'Opciones de configuración de la base de datos de Toyota del Ecuador y acceso a los formularios de contacto',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('toyotaec_configuracion'),
            'access arguments' => array('administer toyotaec pages'),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        ),
        //...
    );
}
```

In an included - and reachable - script (assume the missing functions and constants exist, since I will not post the whole code):

```
function toyotaec_configuracion() {
    $form_specs_alt = array(
        'formularios' => array(
            '#markup' => sprintf(<<<MARKUP
<div class="forms">
    <span class="caption">Listados de los formularios</span>
    <ul class="form-results-menu">
        <li><a href="?q=%s/webform-results/table">Registros de Contacto (Tomebamba)</a></li>
        <li><a href="?q=%s/webform-results/table">Registros de Cotizaci&oacute;n (Tomebamba)</a></li>
        <li><a href="?q=%s/webform-results/table">Registros de Redirecci&oacute;n</a></li>
        <li><a href="?q=%s/webform-results/table">Registros de Curr&iacute;culum</a></li>
        <li><a href="?q=%s/webform-results/table">Registros de Solicitudes de Actualizaci&oacute;n de Software de Chasis Prius 3g</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
MARKUP
                , drupal_lookup_path('source', FORM_ALIAS_CONTACTO)
                , drupal_lookup_path('source', FORM_ALIAS_COTIZAR)
                , drupal_lookup_path('source', FORM_ALIAS_SELECCIONAR)
                , drupal_lookup_path('source', FORM_ALIAS_TRABAJA_CON_NOSOTROS)
                , drupal_lookup_path('source', FORM_ALIAS_CAMPANIA_SERVICIO_3G)
            )
        )
    );
    if (!user_access('access all webform results'))
    {
        $form_specs_alt = array();
    }
    $form_specs = array(
        'nuevos_numeros_de_chasis' => array(
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => t('Números de Chasis'),
            '#description' => t("Archivo .csv con el contenido de la tabla de chasis necesarios para la actualización"),
            '#required' => false,
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'csv'),
                'file_validate_size' => array(32*1024*1024),
            ),
        ),
        'instrucciones_nuevos' => array(
            '#markup' => '<div class="instrucciones">Para obtener el archivo necesario, tome el archivo de hoja de calculo (formato .xls o .xlsx, de Microsoft Excel) de chasis registrados y, seleccionando la primer hoja de c&aacute;lculo, vaya al men&uacute; "Archivo" &gt; "Guardar como", y elija el formato "csv". Luego, en los campos m&aacute;s abajo en este formulario, coloque respectivamente el archivo exportado.</div>'
        ),
        'adjuntar' => array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => 'Conservar las entradas anteriores (no se incluirían los números repetidos)',
            '#attributes' => array('checked' => 'checked'),
            '#order_by' => 'text',
            '#sort_oerder' => 'asc'
        ),
        'borrar' => array(
            '#attributes' => array("style" => "min-width: 150px; min-height: 150px"),
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'Elementos a borrar',
            '#multiple' => true,
            '#options' => array(),
        ),
        'instrucciones_existentes' => array(
            '#markup' => '<div class="instrucciones">Puede borrar uno o más números de chasis existentes. Mantenga la tecla Ctrl presionada al mismo tiempo que hace click sobre un elemento para seleccionarlo sin perder los anteriormente seleccionados. De esta forma usted podrá seleccionar más de un elemento en simultáneo para su eliminación.</div>'
        ),
        'instrucciones' => array(
            '#markup' => '<div class="instrucciones">El proceso de actualización consistirá en lo siguiente:<ul><li>Se borrarán aquellas entradas que se hayan seleccionado en la lista anterior.</li><li>Si no está seleccionada la tilde para conservar las entradas anteriores, y se sube un archivo, entonces todas las entradas se eliminarán.</li><li>Se agregarán las entradas incluídas en el archivo, si el mismo fue subido y es un archivo válido.</li></ul>Puede omitir la carga del archivo o el borrado de elementos existentes.</div>'
        )
    );
    $form = system_settings_form($form_specs_alt + $form_specs);
    array_pop($form['#submit']); //no quiero que me guarde variables de configuracion
    return $form;
}
```

This whole code **works** - have no trouble at all with it - and creates an administration **FORM** which is displayed in the admin module pages and overlay.

**My question is**: How can I do to create a **SIMPLE** page - suitable for the admin module pages and overlay - with no form (in this case I use system_settings_form) at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new hook_menu entry but as 'page callback' use a custom function. That custom function must return the content that will be delivered to user (as a renderable array or HTML code).

Maker sure your path is under admin/config/*.

Something like this:

```
    'admin/config/toyotaec-antoher' => array(
        'title' => 'Configuración de Toyota del Ecuador',
        'description' => 'Opciones de configuración de la base de datos de Toyota del Ecuador y acceso a los formularios de contacto',
        'page callback' => 'my_custom_function',
        'access arguments' => array('administer toyotaec pages'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    ),
```

And:

```
function my_custom_function() { 
  return '<div>My custom page content.</div>';
}
```

Comment: Newbie question: any array is considered renderable? (i.e. if their elements are primitive values like string, integers, or arrays following the #-marked convention)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Any array with those properties that will be passed to `drupal_render()` (or simply `render()`) is considered a render array; it depends on context. If you return an array from a page callback it will be run through `drupal_render()`

Comment: ty :D. still have a lot to learn, and i'm against the clock :s.